# Could not find a kernel matching R using anaconda jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel

I'm Using Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1. Python kernel is working well. Only when I try to use the R kernel I get this problem.

I tried to uninstall and installed it (anaconda), and also tried to install it from (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) still not working (the R kernel). This is my screenshot after I tried it all.

[image: kernel not found]